# How to execute system command in mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is the code,

```
delimiter //
create procedure trig ()
begin
    declare cmd varchar(50);
    set cmd = "sh /home/yogaraj/Documents/Maastry/firefox.sh";
    system cmd;
end //

delimiter ;
```

But I can't execute system command. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Where did you see that `system` is valid in a stored procedure? Link to the documentation please...

Comment: I want to execute the system command inside procedure. I don't know whether it is valid or not. Suggest any alternatives if there are.

Comment: What errors are you getting

Comment: Take a look [here](https://patternbuffer.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/triggering-shell-script-from-mysql/) - but I'm downvoting this question because I got this as a result of a simple Google. Take the tour, check out the "help us to help you" blog (bottom left of page) and visit the help centre(bottom right). These sites are a great resource and you will get all the more from them if you follow the guidelines (p.s. welcome to the forum!). Didn't vote to close because it's a reasonable DBA type request.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be accomplished. Why ?

According to [Can MySql stored proc call a system cmd? (from July 19, 2009 11:47AM)](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,272437,272447#msg-272447)

> This question is asked several times a week. The answers are (i) not out of the box, for very good reasons, (ii) you could write and link into your server a UDF which calls the operating system, but that would create a glaring security issue for your app.

For example, I have written about using `system` before : [Why would I use the MySQL "system" command?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41184/why-would-i-use-the-mysql-system-command/41187#41187). In my post, I showed how easy it would be to step into the operating system with

```
mysql> \! bash
[root@**** ~]# exit
exit
mysql>
```

Imagine what one could do in the OS because of such a breach.

Usually, [stored procedures are used to prevent SQL injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68701/how-does-stored-procedure-prevents-sql-injection). If `system` was allowed within a stored procedure, that eliminates such security.

You will have to run the script as follows

```
mysql> system /home/yogaraj/Documents/Maastry/firefox.sh
```

or

```
mysql> \! /home/yogaraj/Documents/Maastry/firefox.sh
```

This is all you can really do